# How to send FlatBuffers ByteBuffer over network?

Tags: java, php, http, networking, flatbuffers

I want to send the ByteBuffer from [FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/) over network to an Android Application.
I tried using `echo $builder->sizedByteArray`, but then I'm wondering how to deserialize this String.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that this bytearray has to be sent in a way suited to binary transmission, not text.

As for deserialization with Java, have you looked here: https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html (make sure you select Java as your language) ? You can use `ByteBuffer.wrap` with a `byte[]` you received over the network.